# Bugsense iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, crash-reports

I'm trying to get bugsense working in my iOS app but the app is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS while initializing the BugSenseCrashController:

```
  BugSenseCrashController *crash =
        [BugSenseCrashController sharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey:@"<Your BugSense API Key>"];
```

My key is correct and I've followed all the instructions listed here: http://www.bugsense.com/docs/ios

Not sure where to go from here.

**EDIT**
I've changed my code so I'm not using userDictionary (don't need it at the moment).  Issue still persists.

**EDIT2**
It seems this is only happening when I run the code on the device (4.3.5) and not in the simulator (4.3).

Comment: Post your crash log here. In userDictionary:myCustomData is myCustomData dictionary object ? Anyway can't help much unless you post your crash log. Set environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES and see what gets overreleased.

Comment: Hi Scott! Can you post more info (stack trace or the exception message)? We haven't had reports of any issues like this before.

Comment: Nick, unfortunately in the process of trying to troubleshoot the issue, I updated my iTouch to 5.0.1 from 4.3.5.  I'm not getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS while on this version of iOS.  I am attempting to restore back to 4.3.5 but I'm unable to do so at the moment.  If i do manage to get this restored and can reproduce the error and produce a stack trace, is there a better way to contact you?

Comment: Scott, you can contact me at nick@bugsense.com

Answer (score 2):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: Well, I already know the line thats causing the problem, I just don't know how to fix it.  It seems it's an issue with iOS 4.3.5 and that build of Bugsense.  I don't seem to have the problem with any other version.

Comment: The `info malloc-history` stack trace can show the execution path leading up to the crash, which will probably make it clear where the issues is.  Either way, would you be able to post a stack trace or the entire exception message in your Question?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following frameworks:
1. SystemConfiguration
2. libz.1.2.5